# Falar qual é a cor predominante

Tags: python, opencv

Exemplo: caso a cor predominante seja um tom de vermelho ou vermelho aparece um print dizendo que é vermelho.

o código funciona e retorna um valor em RGB, o que eu não estou conseguindo e dizer qual e a cor predominante, Exemplo: quando o código retornar o valor em exemplo :RGB (228,47,53), em vez de aparecer o código em rgb apareça a cor em si (vermelho, verde, azul)

um exemplo de codigo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216772/how-to-check-rgb-colors-against-a-color-range , so nao estou conseguindo aplicar ao meu codigo

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

def grab_frame(cap):
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    return cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

def atualizar(i):
    img = grab_frame(captura)
    im1.set_data(img)
    im2.set_data(retangulo(img))

def close(event):
    if event.key == 'q':
        plt.close(event.canvas.figure)

def unique_count_app(a):
    colors, count = np.unique(a.reshape(-1,a.shape[-1]), axis=0, return_counts=True)
    return colors[count.argmax()]

def retangulo(img):
    r, g, b = contar_kmeans(img)
    h, w, c = img.shape
    rect = np.zeros((h, w, 3), np.uint8)
    rect[0:h, 0:w] = (r,g,b)
    return rect

def contar_kmeans(img):
    data = np.reshape(img, (-1,3))
    data = np.float32(data)
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
    flags = cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS
    compactness, labels, centers = cv2.kmeans(data, 1, None, criteria, 10, flags)
    return centers[0]

#Inicialização
captura = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
imagem = grab_frame(captura)

#Cria os dois subplots
ax1 = plt.subplot(1,2,1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(1,2,2)


#Cria duas imagens nos subplots
im1 = ax1.imshow(imagem)
im2 = ax2.imshow(retangulo(imagem))

#Animação e atualização
ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), atualizar, interval=200)
print (imagem)
#Fechar
cid = plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", close)
#Mostrar o gráfico
plt.show()
```

Comment: Qual é a dúvida? Está acontecendo algum erro? Está dando uma resposta que não é a correta? O que tá acontecendo?

Comment: Opa Desculpa acabei não explicando tao certo,o código funciona e retorna um valor em RGB, o que eu não estou conseguindo e dizer qual e a cor predominante, Exemplo: quando o código retornar o valor em exemplo :RGB (228,47,53), em vez de aparecer o código em rgb apareça a cor em si (vermelho, verde, azul)

Comment: Edita a sua pergunta com estas informações. Dessa maneira as pessoas que lerem ela já vão ter mais ferramentas pra te ajudar

Comment: Se você possui `RGB(228,47,53)`, não seria apenas verificar qual é o maior valor para saber a cor predominante?

Comment: esta parte que eu não estou conseguindo, não consigo fazer a verificação, exemplo caso o código em rgb(204, 195, 253), a cor predominante seria azul correto.

Comment: Sim, mas se atente ao fato de que a biblioteca OpenCV trabalha no espaço de cores BGR como padrão, então (204, 195, 253) na verdade possui o vermelho como predominante. A não ser que seja realizada uma conversão: `cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`

Comment: Sim correto estou tentando criar o Código para fazer essa verificação mas não estou conseguindo progredir muito, mas agradeço já me deu uma ideia de como prosseguir

Comment: resolvi dessa forma `def retangulo(img):
    r, g, b = contar_kmeans(img)
    h, w, c = img.shape
    rect = np.zeros((h, w, 3), np.uint8)
    rect[0:h, 0:w] = (r,g,b)
    if r > g and r > b:
        print("Red")
    elif g > r and g > b:
        print("Green")
    else:
        print("blue")
    return rect`

Comment: so que acabo caindo em um outro problema, que ele sempre vai fica falando infinitamente alguma cor, queria que so falasse quando eu colocar algum objeto na frente ou algo parecido

Answer (score 0):

Se vc quer retornar a cor como (vermelho, amarelo, verde), primeiramente recomendo vc converter de RGB para HSV, e depois fazer um range de cada cor, como por exemplo,

```
lower_blue = np.array([90,109,50],np.uint8)
upper_blue = np.array([120,255,255],np.uint8)
```

Após seu programa retornar a cor predominante vc comparar se ela está dentro desse range. Imagino que isso funcione.